# how to use sub-string with awk

Tags: bash, awk, substring

I am using following line to write some data to the file:

`cat $srcfile | awk -v p=$prefix '{printf("XX_%s%s XX_%s\n", p, $1, $1);}' > $dstfile`

How can I change XX by two first letters of $1?

Comment: Please add samples of input and output in your post to make question more clear and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `substr`:

```
echo "abcdef 12345" | awk -v p="foo" '{x=substr($1,1,2); printf("%s_%s%s %s_%s\n", x, p, $1, x, $1);}'
```

Output:

```
ab_fooabcdef ab_abcdef
```